# Create build of Windows Service Project with CCnet

Tags: c#, asp.net, service, cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

I have been creating deployment Packages for ASP Web projects through ccnet like this
`<exec>
    <description>Asp.NET Compiler</description>
    <executable>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe</executable>
    <baseDirectory>.\Code</baseDirectory>
    <buildArgs>-errorstack -nologo -f -v ~ -p .\WebProject ..\Deploy</buildArgs>
    <successExitCodes>0</successExitCodes>
</exec>`

I was wondering how can I create a deployment package for a Windows Service Project?

Answer (score 0):

The `aspnetcompiler` is creating a deployable version of your site. Building a windows service in `release` mode is equivalent for most other project types, including windows services.

This can be achieved with the `msbuild` task.

See http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/MsBuild_Task